# How to stop people disturbing a ZFS dataset which is only used to receive?

Tags: zfs

I have two machines, "sender" and "receiver".

Sender runs the following command each night:

```
zfs send -i bpool/backups@2018-09-04 bpool/backups@2018-09-05 | ssh receiver /sbin/zfs receive bpool/backups
```

The sends the latest of bpool/backups from sender to receiver.  (Dates are automatically generated each night.)

If someone (on receiver) does as little as:

```
cd /bpool/backups
ls
```

it breaks the nightly backup job, with the following error:

```
root@sender:~# zfs send -i bpool/backups@2018-09-04 bpool/backups@2018-09-05 | ssh recevier /sbin/zfs receive bpool/backups
cannot receive incremental stream: destination bpool/backups has been modified
since most recent snapshot
warning: cannot send 'bpool/backups@2018-09-04': Broken pipe
```

(I assume this is because of updated atimes, or similar.)

How can I stop this from happening?  (If I made receiver:/bpool/backups read-only how would the receive work?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zfs recv -F` will force the receiving dataset to roll back to the previous received snapshot. Turning off atime will only address the issue of people examining the files on the backup, but if there are any other changes, you'll want to use the -F flag instead.

Comment: Notice though that the [docs](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/8/zfs-recv.8.html#F) say that `-F` will **destroy** snapshots and file systems that do not exist on the sending side. That will possibly include older ones.

Answer (score 7):

You *can indeed* set your target dataset to be readonly (by setting the zfs property `readonly=on` directly on the target dataset or one of its parents). This will not hinder you from receiving newer snapshots, because `readonly` for a dataset only means, that you cannot make changes to the files (, directories and attributes) inside.

This is different from setting `readonly=on` when you import a pool. With a pool `readonly` means, that IO cannot write anything to the pool's backend.

I for one am not quite happy with the accepted answer, because simply by principle, noone should make any changes whatsoever on a dataset that is meant to only receive anyway.

Another reason why I'm against the `-F` switch is, that when you receive incremental snapshot data (`zfs send -i data@older-snap data@newer-snap`), then the `-F` switch *also* results in snapshots being deleted from the backup dataset that do not also exist in the source dataset (albeit only newer ones). It is always good to design your services so that they fail (and report errors) when they encounter something unexpected (instead of just ignoring errors).

For a backup pool/dataset, you might also want to set `atime=off`, because that too contradicts its purpose.

Edit: Ah and one should add, that you can keep these properties set only on the receiving dataset (which would be overwritten in case they were set directly in the source dataset) by using `zfs receive -o atime=off -o readonly=on`

Comment: this is the right answer

Answer (score 4):

Turning off access time update should be enough:

```
zfs set atime=off bpool/backup
```

Comment: Does the receiving dataset even have to be mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Personnally I prefer to directly mount the snapshots as read-only, that way we don't even modify snapshots by construction.

If you are on an encrypted dataset, first run the following commands to load the keys:

```
$ sudo zfs load-key -a
```

Then just mount it, for example as follows (no need for `-o ro` options):

```
$ mkdir /tmp/zp
$ sudo mount -t zfs zpool_my_passport/backup/2020_Dell_laptop@2021_01_05_-_test_update /tmp/zp/
```

But if a modification happens, indeed `zfs recv -F` is really practical (I'm just a bit afraid to have data losts with `-F` so that's why I prefer this method).